# Second and Third Multiple Value Parameters Not Passing Through To Drillthrough Report In SSRS 2012

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've found a lot of help online about passing multi-value parameters to a drillthrough report in SSRS.  I haven't found a successful response for *multiple* multi-value parameters in SSRS.

To explain, I have the following summary report:

```
SELECT

SH.[USER-ID],
U.[DESCRIPTION] AS "USER NAME",
COUNT (J.[JOB-NO]) AS "NUMBER-OF-JOBS"

FROM

[RM-JOB] AS J
LEFT OUTER JOIN
[RM-STAGE-HISTORY] AS SH ON SH.[JOB-NO] = J.[JOB-NO]
JOIN
[CO-USERS] AS U ON U.[USER-NAME] = J.[RAISED-BY]
LEFT JOIN
[IH-LOCATION] L ON J.[PLACE-REF] = L.[PLACE-REF]
LEFT JOIN
[IH-LOC-ATTR] LA ON  J.[PLACE-REF] = LA.[PLACE-REF] AND LA.[ATTRIB-CODE] = 'SBU'


WHERE

J.[DATE-LOGGED] BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2
AND
SH.[STAGE-CODE] IN ('06')
AND
SH.[STAGE-DATE] BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2
AND
J.[RAISED-BY] = SH.[USER-ID]
AND
LA.[SUB-ATTRIB-CODE] IN (@SBU)
AND
J.[RAISED-BY] IN (@RAISEDBY)
AND
J.[LATEST-PRIORITY] IN (@Priority)
AND
L.[MGT-AREA] IN (@MGTAREA)

GROUP BY

SH.[USER-ID],
U.[DESCRIPTION]

ORDER BY

U.[DESCRIPTION]
```

And the following Details Report:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT

    J.[RAISED-BY],
    J.[JOB-NO],
    LEFT(J.[PLACE-REF],3) AS [SCHEME],
    J.[PLACE-REF],
    L.[MGT-AREA],
    LA.[SUB-ATTRIB-CODE] SBU,
    J.[JOB-STATUS],
    CONCAT(IP.[PRIORITY-CODE], '- ',IP.DESCRIPTION) [INITIAL-PRIORITY],
    CONCAT(LP.[PRIORITY-CODE], '- ',LP.DESCRIPTION) [LATEST-PRIORITY],
    J.[DATE-LOGGED],
    J.[CURRENT-STAGE-CODE],
    J.[ORIG-LOGGED-VALUE] AS "LOGGED-VALUE",
    J.[TOTAL-VALUE],
    J.[SHORT-DESCRIPTION],
    J.[CONTRACTOR],
    C.[DESCRIPTION],
    J.[CL-ANALYSIS-CODE-ELEMENT],
    J.[CL_ANALYSIS_CODE_ELEMENT##2],
    J.[CL_ANALYSIS_CODE_ELEMENT##3],
    J.[CL_ANALYSIS_CODE_ELEMENT##4],
    J.[CL_ANALYSIS_CODE_ELEMENT##5],
    SH.[JOB-AMENDED]

    FROM

    [RM-JOB] AS J
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [RM-CONT] as C ON C.CONTRACTOR = J.CONTRACTOR
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
           [JOB-NO], 
           CASE WHEN MAX([STAGE-CODE]) = ('11') THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS "JOB-AMENDED"
    FROM
    [RM-STAGE-HISTORY] 
    WHERE [STAGE-CODE] IN ('06','11')
    GROUP BY [JOB-NO]) AS SH ON J.[JOB-NO] = SH.[JOB-NO] 

    LEFT JOIN
    [RM-PRIORITY] IP ON J.[INITIAL-PRIORITY] = IP.[PRIORITY-CODE]
    LEFT JOIN
    [RM-PRIORITY] LP ON J.[INITIAL-PRIORITY] = LP.[PRIORITY-CODE]
    LEFT JOIN
    [IH-LOCATION] L ON J.[PLACE-REF] = L.[PLACE-REF]
    LEFT JOIN
    [IH-LOC-ATTR] LA ON  J.[PLACE-REF] = LA.[PLACE-REF] AND LA.[ATTRIB-CODE] = 'SBU'

    WHERE

    J.[DATE-LOGGED] BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2
    AND
    J.[RAISED-BY] = @RAISEDBY
    AND
    LA.[SUB-ATTRIB-CODE] IN (@SBU)
    AND
    J.[LATEST-PRIORITY] IN (@Priority)
    AND
    L.[MGT-AREA] IN (@MGTAREA)
```

Now, @Date1, @Date2 and @RAISEDBY are all single value and work fine, but @SBU, @Priority and @MGTAREA are all multi-value. In all three cases, I've set the multivalue parameters to Allow Multiple Values, and in the textbox Action, I've set all three Parameters to split out the multiple values as suggested elsewhere: =SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!SBU.Value, ","), ",")

However, when I select more than one value for @Priority or @MGTAREA, then the details report is blank. This is the first time I think I've done this and I'm wondering if I've done anything obvious wrong, or whether SSRS can even handle three multi-value parameters on the same drillthrough.

Any help gratefully accepted, I've been literally staring at this for most of a day!

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset queries are directly in the dataset (i.e. you are not using a stored proc) then there is no need to do any SPLIT and/or JOIN methods on them. SSRS will automatically inject a comma separated list in place of your @parameters in your query.

Make sure your parameter datatypes in the parameter properties are set to text (even if they are numeric)

Comment: The parameters are set to text.  The queries themselves are currently in an SP, but I pasted the SP code in here to see if I'd made an error. I might try to run the code client-side tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to execute the detailed report within visual studio (not as a sub report)?

Comment: I've tested the query in SSMS with one parameter apiece and it works fine. I might try running it as a separate report in VS tomorrow and see how I get on, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I was attempting to run the details report as a Stored Procedure. Both the responses led me to trying to run the details report as client-side code. It worked perfectly that way.

It appears that Stored Procedure reports don't like multiple multi-value parameters!